# How to define CSS selector, but not when it's nested within itself?

Tags: css, css-selectors

How to define a CSS selector that targets only the highest level element of itself, but not those elements that are nested within the same selector itself?

For example the style rules gets applied to `.card` element, but not `.card .card` or `.card .card .card` elements... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can negate the styling of the children with the [Descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator)

```css
.card {
    border: 1px solid black; /* orig style */
    height: 200px;
    width: 50%;
}

.card {
    border: 5px solid red; /* "highest level element of itself" */
}

.card .card {
    border: 1px solid black; /* children of the "highest level element" */
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm actually using SCSS, and in this occasion am overwriting a style rule as built by my custom variable configurations in Bootstrap framework... If I need to explicitly define an overwriting rule for the nested instances of this main selector, then I'm losing configurability with variables (unless I try to mimic the original way of configuration for this rule as done by the framework itself). It seems this is what I need to do if there is no other way.

Comment: I see. That may be the case but I think that is a separate issue - perhaps programmers knowledgeable in `SCSS` can help out. For now, another approach I can suggest is some markup changes - just have another class on the highest level element so you can increase `CSS` specificity or perhaps if the highest `.card` element's parent is determinable you can use the [Child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator)